Azure Data Factory dynamic excel data flow
my scenario is the following: I created a pipeline that work on an Excel file and is triggered by the upload of the Excel in a Blob Storage. The filename is passed as a parameter to the pipeline from the trigger. I then apply a lookup and then a forEach where I copy each row of the excel to different SQL tables. Now I have two problems:

Sometimes some rows are deleted manually from the excel before uploading, but even if they are empty the Lookup activity reads them as rows full of null, while I would like to skip them. I tried to filter them out with a data flow, but I do not understand how to configure it because nothing appears in the dropdown menus and I don't know what to write as a dynamic content and how to write it. For example, I tried to use a Select to rename the columns:

but then in the filter activity nothing appears in the Input schema section so I don't know how to make it work


In the last part of my pipeline, when I copy data to SQL table I do
it with a json mapping:
@json(' {   "type": "TabularTranslator",   "mappings": [
{
"source": {
"name": "sampleId"
},
"sink": {
"name": "sample_id",
"physicalType": "int"
}
},
{
"source": {
"name": "parameterId"
},
"sink": {
"name": "parameter_id",
"physicalType": "int"
}
},
{
"source": {
"name": "resultText"
},
"sink": {
"name": "result_text",
"physicalType": "varchar",
"nullValue": "null"
}
},
{
"source": {
"name": "resultSymbol"
},
"sink": {
"name": "result_symbol",
"physicalType": "varchar",
"nullValue": "null"
}
},
{
"source": {
"name": "resultNumber"
},
"sink": {
"name": "result_number",
"physicalType": "decimal",
"nullValue": "null"
}
}   ],   "typeConversion": true,   "typeConversionSettings": {
"allowDataTruncation": true,
"treatBooleanAsNumber": false   } } ')
But even if the result_number column is nullable and the input
contains a null, I get an error:
ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '' for column name 'result_number' from type 'String'
(precision:, scale:) to type 'Decimal' (precision:10, scale:2).
Additional info: The input wasn't in a correct format.
This is what I see in the input tooltip:

How can I make it insert a NULL in the db instead of failing?


Thank you
EDIT1
Some more details on my pipeline. This is where I think I should put the dataflow:

And here's the details about the dataset:



can you ad how you are using dynamic dataflow

@PratikLad I am not using it yet, I think I need to use it to solve my problem but if you have another suggestion I'm here to listen. I tried to add some more details, hope it is what you meant...if not, feel free to ask for more!


Sometimes some rows are deleted manually from the excel before uploading, but even if they are empty the Lookup activity reads them as rows full of null, while I would like to skip them.

To skip the rows with full of null You can use filter activity as below:

Take filer activity and pass the lookup output to it as items as below.

Thena add condition as below where we are comparing each item if it is null or not if all items are null then row would get skipped;

@or(or(or(or(not(equals(item().sampleld,null)),not(equals(item().parameterld,null))),not(equals(item().resultText,null))),not(equals(item().resultSymbol,null))),not(equals(item().resultNumber,null)))



ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '' for column name 'result_number' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'Decimal' (precision:10, scale:2). Additional info: The input wasn't in a correct format.

In Copy activity, Value in additional column can be of string only. It does not accept null value there is the cause of error you are getting.
You can use DataFlow instead of Copy activity to resolve the issue

First create dummy file with your data in single row and add it as source in dataflow.

My source Data Preview:

Create parameters in the data flow with default value as null() as per your respective datatype as below:

Then pass the values from foreach to this parameter in dataflow activity parameter as below:  
Then in Dataflow take Derived column transformation and create columns with expressions using the above parameters as below image and expressions:

resultText1 - iif(equals($resultTextparam,''), toString(null()), $resultTextparam)
resultSymbol1 - iif(equals($resultSymbolparam,''), toString(null()), $resultSymbolparam)



Then take select column transformation and select only the columns you created in derived column and rename it to original column name:
In sink map the column properly and copy the data:


Final output:


I followed your guid but I get this error:
Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': Operation failed: "This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint."
I searched the Internet and found that I have to connect through auth keys instead of managed identitiy, but if I try that i get a 403 error

What is your source blob storage or ADLS?

It is blob storage. I solved by allowing access from every network and not only selected IP addresses (out of curiosity, why do I have to do that and I can't simply have both key auth and IP-based firewall rules?). Anyway, now it work but my problem is solved only partially: when an empty cell in encounterd in the data flow, for example in result_number column, the default value is copied instead of NULL

can you add the new error or problem in question?

I don't have any new error. In the second part of my question I asked "How can I insert a NULL in the db instead of failing?". Now that I followed your guide, the same input does not fail anymore but a 1.1 (default value) is copied in the resultNumber column instead of NULL
